# Trigger not assigning a value as expected

Tags: trigger, custom-object, lookup

I have a Student object that has a look up relationship to a Coach object. When a student is created, I need to assign a coach to that student, based on which coach has the least amount of students.
The trigger I wrote is this:

```
trigger trigger_AssignCoachToStudent on Student__c (before insert) {

    for (Student__c newStudent: Trigger.New) {
        // Query the database for the coach who has the least amount of students
        AggregateResult[] assignedCoachResults = [SELECT Coach__c FROM Student__c WHERE Coach__c != '' GROUP BY Coach__c  ORDER BY count(Id) ASC LIMIT 1];

        if (assignedCoachResults.size() > 0) {
            String assignedCoachName = (String)assignedCoachResults[0].get('Coach__c');
            Coach__c assignedCoach = new Coach__c(Name=assignedCoachName);

            newStudent.Coach__c = assignedCoach.id;
        } else {
            // Error
            newStudent.addError('Unable to assign a Coach');
        }
    }
}
```

I had originally tried doing this with an `after insert` but found out that at that point, the object is read-only.

When I create a Student with this trigger in place, the Student is saved successfully.

What am I missing / have incorrect in my trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
        String assignedCoachName = (String)assignedCoachResults[0].get('Coach__c');
        Coach__c assignedCoach = new Coach__c(Name=assignedCoachName);

        newStudent.Coach__c = assignedCoach.id;
```

`Coach__c` is an Id value. You need to assign that value directly to `newStudent.Coach__c`. When you create the instance `assignedCoach`, you're moving the Id value to the Name field, and then assigning the value `assignedCoach.id`, which is `null`.

While your aggregate query will work, you're running it in a loop, and will encounter SOQL limit errors if this trigger runs on more than 100 Students in a transaction (at the latest - other SOQL running in this transaction counts against the limit too).

You should work to bulkify this trigger by, for example, changing `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT N`, where `N` is the count of Students. You can then iteratively assign each Student to the next Coach in line, or implement more sophisticated logic to smooth the distribution.

Comment: But when I ran this in workbench, assignedCoah is an object with an id.

Comment: tried it and it works. Weird that workbench is different...

Comment: As written, assignedCoach will never have an Id as it's not interested.

Comment: awesome, thanks. So if I had a field in coach I wanted to evaluate, say Gender, how would you do that from this value?

Comment: You'd need to query for that value. Aggregate queries cannot include non-grouped, non-aggregated values, so most likely you'd need a separate SOQL query.

Answer (score 0):

'assignedCoachResults[0].get('Coach__c')' returns the id of coach which has least number of students. So you just assign it to the new student.

```
if (assignedCoachResults.size() > 0) {
            String assignedCoachId = (String)assignedCoachResults[0].get('Coach__c');

            newStudent.Coach__c = assignedCoachId;
}
```

That being said, you trigger is not bulkified, You have to move the SOQL out of for loop.

```
trigger trigger_AssignCoachToStudent on Student__c (before insert) {
    AggregateResult[] assignedCoachResults = [SELECT Coach__c FROM Student__c WHERE Coach__c != '' GROUP BY Coach__c  ORDER BY count(Id) ASC LIMIT 1];

    String assignedCoachId; 
    if (assignedCoachResults.size() > 0) {
             assignedCoachId = (String)assignedCoachResults[0].get('Coach__c');
    }
    for (Student__c newStudent: Trigger.New) {
            if(assignedCoachId!=null){
                newStudent.Coach__c = assignedCoach.id;
            } else {
            // Error
            newStudent.addError('Unable to assign a Coach');
        }
    }
}
```